# About:application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Tags: iphone

Here is my problem. I inserted:

```
NSLog(@"EXECUTED");
```

in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to see if the method gets invoked. On iPhone simulator, `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` does get invoked, because I can see `"EXECUTED"` in the console. But on my iPod touch, the exact same method does not get invoked, because nothing is printed my console, and my iPod touch screen remains black.
In order to find out this has nothing to do with my iPod touch, I created another very simple app, and inserted:

```
NSLog(@"EXECUTED");
```

in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.The `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method does get invoked on both iPhone simulator and my iPod touch, because `"EXECUTED"` appears when the simple app runs on both iPhone simulator and my iPod touch.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Not Clear what you want to say?

Comment: What else happens in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` around your `NSLog` statement in the app where it breaks? Can you post more code?

Comment: Just detects the current device and load corresponding view controller.I'd like to mention that this app doesn't crash.Sorry I've know idea how to post code.

Comment: Thank you

Problem solved!Here's the thing:I selected the file XXXXXXXXXXXX-info.plist and I found the two options:Main nib file base name(iPad):MainWindowForIPad and Main nib file base name (iPhone):MainWindow.And I add an option which is Main nib file base name and set its value to "MainWindow" then everything works exactly the same on my iPod touch as on iPhone simulator.

Answer (score 0):

application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: will execute and display "EXECUTED" on your Xcode console for simulators and when u launch application in device, not in simulator, "EXECUTED" will be displayed on device console. for device console u have to go to

Xcode -> organizers -> devices -> select your device -> console.

Comment: Thank you.Yes,I selected the console of my device,but I still can't see the string "EXECUTED" appear,which indicates application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: won't get invoked.As I mentioned in another very simple app,application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: did get invoked on my iPod touch.

Comment: Thank you

Problem solved!Here's the thing:I selected the file XXXXXXXXXXXX-info.plist and I found the two options:Main nib file base name(iPad):MainWindowForIPad and Main nib file base name (iPhone):MainWindow.And I add an option which is Main nib file base name and set its value to "MainWindow" then everything works exactly the same on my iPod touch as on iPhone simulator.